# Specify type that is a subtype

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class, extends, typing

We are specifying an abstract class as well as implementation like this:

```
from abc import ABC
class Base(ABC):
    ...

class Type1(Base):
    def __init__(self, var1: str):
        ...
```

then we are trying to use it in this way

```
from typing import Dict
constructors: Dict[str, Base]= {'type1': Type1}

constructors['type1']("")  # Error here
```

But we are getting an error in our IDE that says `Base` is not callable -- which is true.  How do we specify that the our dictionary values are descendants of the `Base` class which *are* callable?

Comment: I didn't have any issues running this

Comment: You want `Dict[str, Type[Base]]`, since `constructors` holds the *types* `Base` (or subtypes), not *instances* of `Base` or its subtypes.

Comment: @chepner can you add this as the answer and possibly explain a little of what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotation `Dict[str,Base]` indicates a `dict` that maps `str` keys to values that are *instances* of `Base` (or its subclasses). You intend the values to be the class `Base` (or one of its subclasses) itself, so you need to use `Type[Base]` instead. (Just like `Base` et al. are instances of the (meta)class `type`.)

```
constructors: Dict[str, Type[Base]] = {'type1': Type1}
constructors['type1']("")
```

Whether your IDE is smart enough tell if `constructors['type1']` is abstract or not is another matter, though.

Comment: Your solution works for IntelliJ.  In my version, IntelliJ was giving me guff.  Thanks!